# Linux - "-y" parameter option in Kickstart file

Tags: linux, automation

Currently I am setting up a Kickstart file which will install the snort software and required dependencies on a Ubuntu server (16.04.2 LTS) using the "%package" section of Kickstart.

The question, can I use the -y" parameter within the "%package" section or something equivalent to say yes to everything as I need to skip the dialogs what pop up during the installation of snort as my job is to setup a automated Linux installation using Kickstart and pressed configuration file.

Note - I know you can use post scripts in Kickstart but my supervisor requires me to use %package section of Kickstart.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this parameter with your package name "--resolvedeps".

Ex:-
Package_name --resolvedeps

It'll resolved all the dependencies.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for getting back to me on this. I have tested this by adding --resolvedeps onto the end of the snort package name like so: snort --resolvedeps and tested my installation and still getting the problem. If it helps im getting a interface error about being on the wrong network interface. As said above, I need to just skip the error like the -y parameter does in Linux.